# Building Convolutional Neural Network for Bull's eye rash recognition

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I need to build a Bull's eye rash recognition system.

I chose to work with Tensorflow+Keras for this. I've batch downloaded about 300 images of bull's eye rash, and same amount of other skin diseases&clean skin images. Here is my model:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(64))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
```

In the process (30 epochs) it does give 90%+ accuracy, however, the system shows only about 65% accuracy on the test set.

Then I tried to crop all the rash images so that they fill the entire image. The result was disappointing, again, I don't know why, but it showed about 55% accuracy on the test set.

Can you give me some suggestions on what to do? Is the model wrong or inefficient? Do I have to use some other ML techniques for this?

Examples of images from my dataset: [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/utU35.jpg), [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pb16W.jpg) and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H09zk.jpg)

Examples of cropped pictures I used for the second attempt: [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vb4hs.jpg), [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DuT5U.jpg) and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D7CHo.jpg)

Comment: What's the proportion of clean/diseased skins in the test set? How is your evaluation done? It could be overfitting as well. Data augmentation could help as well. But with this little information here, it's hard to say what can be done to achieve better results.

Comment: @kluu proportion is equal. What do you mean by how is evaluation done? What more information should I provide?

Answer (score 2):

Well, hard to start with this information.

1) have you tried pre-processing your images?

2) have you tried to load in a pre trained VGG16 network (looks close to yours), then you only need to train the dense layers.

```
base_model = VGG16(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=target_shape)

model_top = Sequential()
model_top.add(Flatten(name='flatten', input_shape=base_model.output_shape[1:]))
model_top.add(Dense(4096, activation='relu', name='fc1'))
model_top.add(Dense(4096, activation='relu', name='fc2'))
model_top.add(Dropout(0.5))
model_top.add(Dense(nr_classes, activation='softmax', name='predictions'))

model_full = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=model_top(base_model.output))

# set the first 25 layers (up to the last convolution block)
# to non-trainable (weights will not be updated)
for layer in model_full.layers[:-5]:
    layer.trainable = False

model_full.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                   optimizer=optimizers.Adam(lr=1e-7))

model_full.summary()
```

3) Create a validation set to see if you overfit the network (validation accuracy decreases, but training accuracy increases).

Comment: Haven't pre-processed images, but may be a good idea. Will try, thank you. Now trying to do train based on Xception. Will try your piece of code, I hope it helps. As for the validation set, I tried it. As far as 30 epochs went validation accuracy went from 0.58 to 0.66 and training accuracy went from 0.47 to 0.93.